# Definition of small $o$

Tags: asymptotics, definition

In one of my homework assignments (in intro to applied mathematics)
there is the following definition:

> Given two functions $f(\epsilon),g(\epsilon)$ that are defined in
>   $D=(0,\epsilon)$ we say that $f(\epsilon)=o(g(\epsilon))$ if there
>   exist a bounded function $c(\epsilon)$ defined for $\epsilon\in D$ s.t
>   $$|f(\epsilon)|<c(\epsilon)|g(\epsilon)|$$ for $\epsilon\in D$.

This definition is a bit confusing to me:

**First,** why is there an $\epsilon$ in the definition of $D$ ? isn't
$\epsilon$ just a dummy variable and can be any number ?

**Second,** taking $c=2$ and $$g(\epsilon)=f(\epsilon)=\epsilon$$ we get
that $f=o(f)$. But I remember that this notation can also be defined
by means that the limit $$\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{f}{g}=0$$ (or
maybe I am just confusing this with the notation of $o$ that I know
for functions $f(n)$ where $n$ is a positive integer).

**Third,** It seems that this definition is the same as saying that there
exist a constant $c$ s.t $$|f(\epsilon)|<c|g(\epsilon)|$$ since we
took $c(\epsilon)$ to be bounded denote $$c=\sup_{\epsilon\in D}c(\epsilon)$$
But the assignments defines $f(\epsilon)=O(g(\epsilon))$ if there
exist a constant $c$ s.t $|f(\epsilon)|<c|g(\epsilon)|$ for $\epsilon\in D$
so either I'm understanding wrong, or $o$ and $O$ means the same.

Is there a problem in the definitions given me (i.e whomever wrote
them probably meant something else) or am I understanding wrong the
definition ?

Comment: Yes, using $\epsilon$ in the definition of $D$ and then saying "for $\epsilon\in D$" is definitely a mistake.

Comment: I'm guessing they wanted the added condition that $c(\epsilon)\to 0$ as $\epsilon\to 0$.  But, as my previous comments suggests, they seem to have botched the definition.

Comment: The definitoin for $O$ seems also a bit flawed if given that way. Better: Assume $f,g$ are defined in a domain $D$ and $0\in\bar D$. Let $c\colon D\to\mathbb R$ be a function such that $|f(x)|\le c(x)|g(x)|$ for all $x\in D$. If $c$ can be chosen such that $c$ is bounded in some neighbourhood of $0$ (not necessarily all of $D$), then $f\in O(g)$ (that is $f$ is "near $0$ essentially not bigger than" $g$). If $c$ can b chosen such that $\lim_{x\to 0} c(x)=0$, then $f\in o(g)$ (that is $f$ is "near $0$ essentially smaller than" $g$).